# Set a default mail signature using VBA In MS Outlook

Tags: vba, email, outlook, signature

Trying to set a default outlook mail signature using VBA. Did that so far using word objects as follows:
`Public Sub setmails()        Application.EmailOptions.EmailSignature.NewMessageSignature = "SIG" Application.EmailOptions.EmailSignature.ReplyMessageSignature = "SIG" End Sub`
Fore sure SIG exists as an HTM file in %appdata%\Microsoft\Signatures

It worked fine until an Outlook update where a signature per mail account can be set, which is a great options but is not presented in any objects of my knowledge.

Now if I run this, the reply signature is ok the new is blank,If I reverse them, the new would be ok, the reply would be blank, so one action cancels the other.

Kind regards,
Nikolay

Also tried registry and in Registry it is a mess I found a key New signature and a reply one where my email account is added. If I manually remove my email account from the second registry entry it all works fine.

Comment: Just a quick note: Since outlook is migrating to the cloud (see the "new outlook") button. VBA (and other extensions) won't be supported long term. There are (commercial) packages available that handle the signatures.

Comment: the new Outlook (Monarch) is a replacement for Windows Mail and Windows Calendar), not for desktop Outlook.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28369793/332059

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/a/32418077/332059